# what types of if statement comparisions are allowed in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating an interactive bar chart that starts with the y axis in the normal orientation (going up from 0 to 100) but after the drop down box is clicked to switch to another chart the y axis inverts and goes from 100 to 0. This all works fine the problem is when the user goes back to the starting chart the y axis stays inverted instead of going back to the normal orientation. I tried to put in an if statement for my selector function below to try to fix this but when I click the drop box it never seems to enter the if statement it just goes to the else statement. So is an if statement comparison allowed for the name of my drop box in d3? or do I need to alter my code?

here is a link to my my charts if anyone wants to have a look:
http://bl.ocks.org/Lecy277/163bcc6bafcf9868153a99e309a95348/e670fe3cbcd18c658cb671b1093610f6c9187af9

```
var selector = d3.select("#drop")
    .append("select")
    .attr("id","dropdown")
    .on("change", function(d){
        selection = document.getElementById("dropdown");
                if (selection== "RegularSeasonQbRating"){
        y1.domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return +d[selection.value];})]);

        yAxis.scale(y1);

        d3.selectAll(".rectangle")
            .transition()
            .attr("height", function(d){
                return height - y1(+d[selection.value]);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i){
                return (width / data.length) * i ;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d){
                return y1(+d[selection.value]);
            })
            .ease("linear")
            .select("title")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.Year+ " "+ d.SuperBowlD+ "cool "+ d[selection.value];
            });

        d3.selectAll("g.y.axis")
            .transition()
            .call(yAxis);}
      else{
        y.domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return +d[selection.value];})]);

        yAxis.scale(y);

        d3.selectAll(".rectangle")
            .transition()
            .attr("height", function(d){
                return height - y(+d[selection.value]);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i){
                return (width / data.length) * i ;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d){
                return y(+d[selection.value]);
            })
            .ease("linear")
            .select("title")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.Year+ " "+ d.SuperBowlD+ "  "+ d[selection.value];
            });

        d3.selectAll("g.y.axis")
            .transition()
            .call(yAxis);}

     });
```

Comment: actually I gave an old link before here is the correct link to the chart         http://bl.ocks.org/Lecy277/163bcc6bafcf9868153a99e309a95348/8a2e4e69306c0e42b9feb9121866c24768db9684

Comment: D3 is a JavaScript library, so **any** valid JavaScript (`if`, ternary operator, etc) is allowed. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: In your `if` you are comparing `selection` (instance of an `Element`) to a string, which is valid, but will always evaluate to false and, hence, execute the `else` block. You probably want `selection.value === "RegularSeasonQbRating"` instead. Since you are in the change handler of that very element, you won't even need to re-select the element as `this` will refer to it. You can safely exchange `selection` for `this`.

Comment: Thank you altocumulus you fixed it with if (this.value === "RegularSeasonQbRating") The first chart now remains in the normal orientation for the y axis while the other inverts it just like I wanted. I did not know I could use this with value like that. I appreciate it